# Using Html Agility Pack to Parse WebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the WebResponse I get from a multiform POST. I want to pull out the H3 tags, but when I go to document.Load the stream, I get null errors like this: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' "

Now I understand my webresponse starts out null, but it fills up eventually. How can I get this to run with the streamreader returning null automatically?

```
//web response stuff here
WebResponse ricochet = webrreq.GetResponse();
Stream stream2 = ricochet.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document= new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

//line with null error below
var collection = document.Load(reader2.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve - the multipart POST you receive is NOT a HTML document...

Comment: I receive a webpage with data on it as a response. When filling out a textBox.Text with reader2.ReadToEnd(), it works fine and I can see the html code. But I can't put it straight into the HtmlDocument.Load function because it is null

Comment: Sidenote: Use the overload of `Load()` that accepts a stream.  No need to read as a string first.

Comment: You need to parse the POST response first to extract the content of textBox.Text and then feed that content to document.Load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Posterity:

I can't assign the collection to document.Load, I first have to Load the stream and then use the Agility pack to find the right nodes again

```
       var thingie = document.Load(reader2.ReadToEnd());
       var collection = thingie.DocumentNode.SelectNode("//etc");
```